# How to prevent button from losing focus when clicking elsewhere on screen?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, jsx, styled-components

I am fairly new to React and I am using styled-components.

```
const Button = styled.button`
  height: 35px;
  width: 85px;
  color: #0288d1;
  border: 1px solid #0288d1;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #cfe8ef;
  }

  &:focus {
    background: #0288d1;
    color: white;
  }

`;
```

I would like to prevent the button from losing focus when the user clicks somewhere else on the screen. Would I need to add additional JavaScript code to do this or is there a CSS property that can help me with this issue?

Comment: This doesn't sound like something that should be done using `focus`. Focus is intended to display where the user is currently interacting, and clicking away means that the user is now "focusing" on something else. If you want to change the style of an element once it is clicked, then keep that style indefinitely, you should use a checkbox and style the `:checked` state, or just use an `.active` class and apply it on click.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
    const setFocus = e => {
        e.target && e.target.focus();
    };

    return (
        <button
            onBlur={e => {
                setFocus(e);
            }}
        >
            My Button
        </button>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `:active` in global stylesheet.

```css
button:active {
   border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

So any time, `button` tags receive this style in active mode.